# Does jmeter timeout SOAP requests

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jmeter, soap-client

While sending WebService(SOAP) requests, I occasionally receive the response below, and always for requests that take more then 60 seconds to complete.

> Thread Name: Test Group A 1-1 Sample
>
> Start: 2010-08-24 11:56:23 MDT Load
>
> time: 60186 Latency: 0 Size in bytes:
>
> 0 Sample Count: 1 Error Count: 1
>
> Response code: 000 Response message: Error parsing HTTP status line "": java.util.NoSuchElementException
>
> Response headers:
>
> SampleResult fields: ContentType:
> DataEncoding: null

Is there a config in Jmeter to set the timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Havent tried these myself.

http://osdir.com/ml/jmeter-dev.jakarta.apache.org/2009-04/msg00179.html states that the

> the JMeter property
>   "httpclient.timeout" works with the
>   HttpClient sampler and SOAP/XML-RPC

Also, the [Release notes](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html)  for **Version 2.3RC3** state

> Added timeout for WebService (SOAP)
>   Sampler

Comment: Thanks... this puts me in the right direction. We'll see if it works.

Comment: Yeah, I thought there was a JMeter assertion that you can use to detect if the time is too long on a request.